# Image editing with Javascript only

Tags: javascript, css, image

I want to edit image in real-time with javascript only. Im new to Js, so this may be dumb question...

I have 3 images:

- Background
- Car one
- Car two

I want to display one on each other in real time. It should look like this:

[image]

And the cars should be moving there and back (I must be able to edit their position without refreshing the page).

Im not asking for complete solution, just a few links or pages and some information where to start with. I know Javascript syntax, I just have never used it in any website. If it's not possible, or it would be too hard, I gonna use flash or Java aplet, Im okay to use jQuery or other Javascript libraries. Thank you for any clues!

Comment: For some reason this reminds me of the "Ajax photo editor" example in Joel's old evidence-based scheduling article. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/10/26.html

Comment: have a look at html5 canvas animations, it may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out jQuery animate and z-indexes. What you'll want to do is with z-index place one on top of the other, then animate with jQuery accordingly.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Comment: I think that's what I need. Sorry for not real question, I have to do this as soon as possible... :/